# Video.js initial dimensions like video resolution

Tags: javascript, flash, video, html5-video, video.js

I use video.js library from: https://github.com/videojs/video.js and i have one issue.

Is it possible to make initial payer dimensions like video resolution if width/height settings not set(for both, html5 & flash video.js mode)?

Native html5 player is ok.

Code presentation example:

html

```
<video id="really-cool-video-native" controls preload="auto">
    <source src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>

<video id="really-cool-video-html5" class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
    <source src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>

<video id="really-cool-video-flash" class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
    <source src="//vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

JS:

```
videojs.options.flash.swf = "//vjs.zencdn.net/c/video-js.swf";

videojs("really-cool-video-html5", {
    controls : true,
    techOrder : ["html5", "flash"]
}, function() {


});

videojs("really-cool-video-flash", {
    controls : true,
    techOrder : ["flash", "html5"]
}, function() {


});
```

CSS:

```
#really-cool-video-native{
    width: 100%;
}
```

URL: https://jsfiddle.net/msthxLkb/

Comment: Are you looking to simply override the width/height, or something more-specific?

Comment: Do you mean without knowing the videos dimensions before loading?